# Select a database table with a button and insert into it with another

Tags: c#, windows, forms, frameworks, entity

I want to save a record using the entity framework with windows forms. On database I have many tables which are similar to each other;  they all have on auto-increment ID column and a string column. What I want is to create a set of buttons that when one of them is pressed it fills a listbox with the designated table. Also another fixed button will insert the string in the fixed textbox  into the table selected by the button pressed previously.

The problem is I can't use the created context item in the second button.

Here is the code for one the buttons on the left:

```
private void btnBB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbItems.DataSource = GsmContext.bbler;
        lbItems.DisplayMember = "bb";
        bb = new bbler();
        bb.bb = txtItem.Text;
        GsmContext.AddTobbler(bb);
    }
```

And here is the code for saving the item in the textbox:

```
 private void SaveItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtItem.Text == string.Empty)
        { this.errorProvider1.SetError(txtItem, "Değer girin"); }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                GsmContext.SaveChanges();
                txtItem.Clear();
            }
            catch (SqlException x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I want to use the context item in another button click event.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have got. My Entity framework model defines all the classes from the database. And then I create an interface IRepository and a DataRepository class.

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> Fetch();
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    T Single(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    T First(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Attach(T entity);
    void Detach(T entity);
    void UpdateChanges(T entity);
    void SaveChanges();
    void SaveChanges(SaveOptions options);

}


public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{

    private ObjectContext _context;

    private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

    public DataRepository()
        : this(new ModelContainer()) //ModelContainer is the name of the EF model class.
    {
    }

    public DataRepository(ObjectContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Fetch()
    {
        return _objectSet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Fetch().AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where<T>(predicate);
    }

    public T Single(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.Single<T>(predicate);
    }

    public T First(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.First<T>(predicate);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> records = from x in _objectSet.Where<T>(predicate) select x;

        foreach (T record in records)
        {
            _objectSet.DeleteObject(record);
        }
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.Attach(entity);
    }

    public void Detach(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.Detach(entity);
    }

    public void UpdateChanges(T entity)
    {
        Add(entity);
        _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
    {
        _context.SaveChanges(options);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
                _context = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then select records like this:

```
    public IList<MyDbClass> GetMyDbClassData()
    {
        IList<MyDbClass> myDbClassData = null;
        using (IRepository<MyDbClass> repository = new DataRepository<MyDbClass>())
        {
            myDbClassData = (from x in repository.GetAll()
                             select x).ToList();
        }
        return myDbClassData;
    }
```

To create a new record:

```
    public void CreateUser(User user)
    {
        using (IRepository<User> repository = new DataRepository<User>())
        {
            repository.Add(user);
            repository.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is too complicated for me. I know the question is messed up but I don't know how else to put it.

Comment: Can you tell me what is GSMContext class in your application?

Comment: Can you show me the code of this class? What is AddTobler doing?

Comment: Here is the code page for the form: http://pastebin.com/ZDc0nT3b. The table name is bbler so adding an item to it would be AddTobbler.

Comment: Ok. What you have to do is to create a new instance of GSMContext everytime you use it and wrap it up in a using statement. You might need to change your structure to accept an object and add it in a method. Then that method will create a new instance of gsmcontext in a using block and you can save changes there.